# How to copy file from container in a pod in a specific namespace?

Tags: kubernetes

Say I have, my-namespace -> my-pod -> my-container
and I have a file located at my-container:/opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.2017-05-02.log. I have applied the below command to copy the file which isn't working,

```
kubectl cp my-namepace/my-pod:/opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.2017-05-02.log -c my-container .
```

Note: I have the tar binary on my container

Error:

```
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
error: open .: is a directory
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

this works for me:

```
$(kubectl exec <pod-name> [-c <container-name>] -it -- cat <file-path>) > <local-file>
```

Comment: Works on pre-1.5.0 versions that don't have `kubectl cp`

Comment: Just a warning, I got corrupt files using this on GCP, then I updated my cluster and kubectl cp worked fine, but this answer still gave me problems. I am not sure why.

Comment: doing `cat` can be lossy and if its a binary file it can get corrupted, `cp` is a better option

Comment: `cat` will only cat ascii content, will not work for binary

Comment: so simple yet so efficient, great work-around

Comment: This works for me. Although I have to do ```ehco `kubectl exec <pod-name> [-c <container-name>] -it -- cat <file-path>` > <local-file>``` because zsh thinks the cat content is a command

Answer (score 54):

What you are asking `kubectl` to do is copy the file catalina.2017-05-02.log to the current context, but the current context is a directory. The error is stating that you can not copy a file to have the name of a directory.

Try giving the copied version of the file a name:

`kubectl cp my-namepace/my-pod:/opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.2017-05-02.log -c my-container ./catalina.2017-05-02.log`.

Comment: Great explanation. Also, Can you please explain why we have this error "tar: Removing leading `/' from member names" and what does it mean?

Answer (score 8):

Source and Destination file name should be same, the below command worked for me:

```
kubectl cp namespace/pod-name:abc.log  .\Desktop\abc.log
```

Answer (score 5):

I noticed it fails when you try to specify the namespace (both as a prefix to the pod identifier and by using `-n` option)
Using the pod identifier alone works for me:

```
kubectl cp postgres-1111111111-11abc:/tmp/dump.csv dump
```

Answer (score 4):

Following command `kubectl cp NameSpace/POD_NAME:/DIR/FILE_NAME /tmp/` works for me.

Answer (score 3):

I found this usage the most convenient for me

```
kubectl cp /tmp/file <your_namespace>/<your_pod>:/tmp/newfile
```

and other direction

```
kubectl cp <your_namespace>/<your_pod>:/tmp/file /tmp/newfile
```

Answer (score 3):

Destination should also be a filename. so, command should be

```
kubectl cp my-namepace/my-pod:/opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.2017-05-02.log -c my-container ./catalina.2017-05-02.log
```

"cat" command works well for ascii files. for other files there would be limitations and copied files might be corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the given options here above it resolve the error but the warning still appears.

```
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
```

BTW the copied file still okay just the warning is a bit confusing.

If you are using absolute path `kubectl cp namespace/pod:/somepath/somfile somepath/somefile` will print the same warning

So if the file is in the working directory of the container the remove the abosulte path and the warning will disappear.

```
k cp "default/name-redis-6d66b898d6-8xdkb:dump.rdb" ./dump.rdb
```

[image]

> [I moved the wanted file to the working dir in the pod](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/58692)

Answer (score 1):

Remove "/" after ":" when specifying container file.

So this

```
kubectl cp my-namepace/my-pod:/opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.2017-05-02.log -c my-container .
```

will turn into this:

```
kubectl cp my-namepace/my-pod:opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.2017-05-02.log -c my-container .
```