# How to copy the filesystem of the pod container on openshift to my local computer?

Tags: docker, openshift, devops

I have to copy a folder data on openshift pod container to my local computer.
I have tried using rsync command for the same.
But it asks for the rsync installation on the openshift pod itself, which I am unable to do due to no root access present on openshift.
Can someone help me in it please?

Comment: `docker cp` command should help you here. On your k8s cluster, go on the node where that pod is runnig and then run `docker cp container-id:/path/to/folder /path/on/host` Note here container-id is the id of the container running inside the pod.

Comment: @mchawre - better still would be `kubectl cp`. However if you are regularly copying data from/to a pod/container- you're almost certainly doing it wrong, and should probably be using volumes.

Comment: @SiHa that's right I was just offering a quick fix in the comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy file from container in a pod in a specific namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43732342/how-to-copy-file-from-container-in-a-pod-in-a-specific-namespace)

Comment: @mchawre Understood - the second part of the comment was directed at the OP.

Comment: @mchawre I have use the cp command and it is only copying the file structure

Comment: @SiHa About that volumes. How to copy data from volumes to our local?

Comment: See the training scenario at https://learn.openshift.com/introduction/ on transferring files into and out of containers. On OpenShift the preferred mechanism is `oc rsync`.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I am getting the following error Connection refused
WARNING: cannot use rsync-daemon: rsync not available in container

Comment: As the message clearly says, you don't have the `rsync` command in your container image. You will need to add it if you want to use `oc rsync`. Otherwise `oc rsync` has the `--strategy tar` option if your image has `tar` in it.